# Is there a way to use multiprocessing to make api calls when you don't know the total number of pages

Tags: python, pagination, get, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use an API (Strava, in case anyone is familiar with it) to get data for a web app using Python's request library. For the API call I am making, there are numerous pages of results. I am currently making one API call per page, and paginating through. I would like to speed up the process of pagination by using multiprocessing. However, I do not know the total number of pages. It doesnt seem to be available from the API, per the documentation:

"If you need to fully go through the full set of results, prefer iterating until an empty page is returned."

I looked in the request headers as well and did not find any information. Is there a way to use multiprocessing to concurrently make API calls when you don't know the number of pages?

Comment: This is too broad/vague IMO.

Comment: They don't want you doing that. They want you to perform one query at a time.